# DevExpress WinForm TabForm Tabs Right Align

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to make the same form as it demonstrated at image below.

[image: Image with tabs aligned right]

Is there any suggestion how to achieve tabs align right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look a the DevExpress [TabPane](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TabPane.class) control.
The [TabPane.Alignment](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TabPane.TabAlignment.property) property should did the trick:

```
TabPane.TabAlignment = Alignment.Far;
```

Answer (score -1):

You must change RightToLeft alignment to Yes from properties or from code in Form_Load

```
xtratab.RightToLeft = True;
```

Comment: BTW, еnabling the RTL locally is the worst idea you can apply to your application ever.